# What's the proper way to add Python modules via PyInstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I am using `PyInstaller` to make my Python script an macOS .app file. It all works, but after building, I need to make some manual `codesign` steps that I want to get rid of. Currently, I add some of my Python modules via `--add-data` and this seems to be the reason, why they are not properly signed. For example:

```
--add-data "/abs/path/to/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy:numpy/"
```

If, I now change this to

```
--add-binary "/abs/path/to/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy:numpy/"
```

I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Unknown Mach-O header: 0x436f7079 in <_io.BufferedReader name='/abs/path/to/lib/python3.9/site-packages/numpy/LICENSE.txt'>
```

Looks like I'm not supposed to add Python modules via `--add-binary`. There are several options now and I'm a bit lost, on what's the correct one to use. Maybe someone could help me out there. The options, that would make sense to me would be:

```
--hidden-import
--collect-binaries #(is this the pendant to --add-binaries, since there also is an --collect-data?)
--collect-all
```

Which one is it, or is it a completely different :D?

Comment: I'm not familiar with PyInstaller, but I would assume that merely having an `import numpy` in your script would be all that is needed for it to be included in the built application.  Why do you feel a need to add it separately?

Comment: Most of the modules are imported by submodules so `PyInstaller` isn't finding them. Importing them in the main script already seems like a redundancy to me.